# What is the difference between "sequel" and "SQL"?

Tags: sql

I want to clarify difference between sequel vs SQL? Any one here know the difference between them?

Comment: It's not really a question. It's a matter of pronunciation. `:)`

Comment: heard that SEQUEL was already a trademark of another company.

Comment: I suppose there is no defference between defference and difference either :)

Comment: I think you need to provide more information.  Both are used for specific technical purposes.  They may be the same (if you are referring to pronunciation).  They may be different (if referring to different products). Where are you encountering the term "sequel"?

Comment: Note that the "sequel" tag you applied is the name of [a database toolkit for Ruby](http://sequel.rubyforge.org), that happens to work with SQL-based RDBMs. So that's one difference, but I presume this is not what you are referring to. I have removed that tag.

Answer (score 51):

in the early 1970s. Initially called SEQUEL (Structured English Query Language) and based on their original language called SQUARE (Specifying Queries As Relational Expressions).SEQUEL was later renamed to SQL by dropping the vowels, because SEQUEL was a trade mark registered by the Hawker Siddeley aircraft company.

Answer (score 15):

They are the same.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL):

> **SQL** (/ˈɛs kjuː ˈɛl/ "S-Q-L"[4]; Structured Query Language[5][6][7][8])
>   is a special-purpose programming language designed for managing data
>   held in a relational database management system (RDBMS).

Some people pronounce it "S-Q-L", while others pronounce it "sequel".

For more on the pronunciation of this term:

**https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7231/how-is-sql-pronounced**

http://patorjk.com/blog/2012/01/26/pronouncing-sql-s-q-l-or-sequel/

Answer (score 5):

I spent some time researching this old issue because it has come up *again* at my company. As John Woo said, it's a matter of *pronunciation*, not spelling. SQL is pronounced "sequel" by many, and there is some history there, beyond just trying to make an acronym out of an initialism. (NASA is an acronym; IBM is an initialism).

But in writing, the best and most consistent way to refer to SQL Server or SQL databases, etc.  is "SQL" --which takes the article "an" based on the initial letter "S". IBM and Microsoft style guides both agree on "an SQL " in writing, even if it might be pronounced "sequel" in some contexts.

Our company was confused on this point for some years because a Google search shows much greater use of "...a SQL " in *English* hits. Also we have long relied on the Microsoft Manual of Style, and their "rule" was easily misinterpreted. They've updated it for the 4th edition--see pp 387-388. SO: In conversation, do what you want, as long as you understand that "sequel" works in English chat, but not necessarily for people whose native language is not English.  **In writing, it's S-Q-L, and the article is "an".**